# Pip process error: Fatal python error, ModuleNotFoundError, etc

Tags: python, pip, kivy

When I write pip, it says

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip
Python path configuration:
PYTHONHOME = (not set)
PYTHONPATH = (not set)

...
```

> Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
> Python runtime state: core initialized
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

What I've tried:
deleting and redownloading Python
deleting and redownloading Pycharm

I don't understand what the problem is. Please help me and create a better world.